# How to display date in firebase with react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Everyone!
I have already connected my app with firebase, but i am not able to display user data on my app:
Could you please go through my code:

```
componentDidMount() {
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user!=null){
    userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
  }else {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Loading");
  }
      }),
firebase.database().ref('Users/').on('value', function (snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot.val()); //this work
  // let name = snapshot.val().name;
  // this.setState ({users :name,}) //this not work
  }); 
    }
```

...... and

```
<View style={styles.contain}>
        <ProfileDetail
          // image={userData.image}
          // textFirst={users.name}
          // point={userData.point}
          textSecond={this.state.name} //. i'd like to display the child on this
          textThird={currentUser.email}
          // onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ProfileExample")}
        />
```

is there anything wrong with my code?
please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
firebase.database().ref('Users/').on('value', function (snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot.val()); //this work
  // let name = snapshot.val().name;
  // this.setState ({users :name,}) //this not work
  });
```

into this:

```
firebase.database().ref('Users/').on('value', ((snapshot) => {
     console.log(snapshot.val()); //this work
     let name = snapshot.val().name;
     this.setState ({users :name,})
  });
```

Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of declaring a normal function.

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal variable lookup rules. So while searching for this which is not present in current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the this from its enclosing scope.

Comment: thank you! its not going warn wrong but i am using this ' textSecond={this.state.name} ' its not display

Comment: what? @MinhTiếnPhạm

Comment: something still wrong, its not work, i call this.state.users but ut underfined

Comment: are u adding it to the state

Comment: sorry for my late  answer but its  work as  another way. thanks!